# How to refer to the bottom in Pages

Tags: pages, documentation

I'm writing a document in Pages, but I want to create a footnote at the bottom of the page. Something like in this image:

[image: example]

How can I do this in Pages?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you are describing a *footnote*, for your information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can insert a footnote by going to **Insert** → **Footnote**

[image]